# AngularJS ng-repeat show spinners

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code. The goal is, to show spinner for each clicked `<span>` - but it doesn't show. Why ?

```
<tr ng-repeat="cat in myItems">
   <td>
      <div class='spinner' ng-show="{{cat.loading}}">
         <img src='/Content/loading.GIF' alt=''/>
      </div>
      <div ng-click="changeItem(cat)" class="contentCell">              
         <span>click me</span>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

controller:

```
$scope.changeItem = function (cat) {
        cat.loading = true;
        catService.doSth(cat.id).then(function (data) {
            cat.loading = false;
        });
    }
```

I see that div has `ng-hide` class, no matter if `ng-show="false"` or `ng-show="true"` it remains there, I think that can be the reason

```
<div class="spinner ng-hide" ng-show="false">
   <img alt="" src="/Content/loading.GIF">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove the `{{}}` in the ng-show, it evaluates an expression, not a value .

```
<tr ng-repeat="cat in myItems">
   <td>
      <div class='spinner' ng-show="cat.loading">
         <img src='/Content/loading.GIF' alt=''/>
      </div>
      <div ng-click="changeItem(cat)" class="contentCell">              
         <span>click me</span>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: it works, thanks. But why did I have to remove the {{}} ? What's the difference ?

Comment: The difference is that with the `{{}}` it uses only the value from the property, and without the `{{}}` on ng-show it evaluates that property in every `$digest` that the `$scope` goes through. Example: `ng-show="{{cat.loading}}"` your variable will always be `true` or `false`, and your function as you click makes the scope go through a `$digest`, so the directive won't see changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
   $scope.cat = false;
    $scope.changeItem = function (cat) {
            $scope.cat.loading = true;
            catService.doSth(cat.id).then(function (data) {
                 $scope.cat.loading = false;
            });
        }
```

You are trying to react the $scope.cat but it does not exist

Comment: Please don't forget the `cat` is the `ng-repeat` object.

Comment: Yes but he was using {{}} so angular js was looking for $scope.cat

Comment: But OP was trying to use the `ng-repeat`object to show a loading, not a `$scope` object property.

Comment: Doesn't matter it can call $scope in the ng-repeat too :) its just another solution showing the spinner without any control from ng-repeat